# add line on existing array with custom value

Tags: arrays, azure, powershell

I need some improvements for the array, I want to add on an Array an extra Line with custom value like the sum for the costs... The way I did, is not the best way, can someone help me?

```
$subs = Get-AzSubscription 

$currentBillingPeriod = Get-AzBillingPeriod -name 202209 #-MaxCount 1
$startDate = $currentBillingPeriod.BillingPeriodStartDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
Write-Host "currentBillingPeriod startDate : " $startDate
$endDate = $currentBillingPeriod.BillingPeriodEndDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
Write-Host "currentBillingPeriod endDate : " $endDate

$report = @()

foreach ($sub in $subs){
$x = "" | Select 'Subscription','cost in Euro','Period'

$acSub = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $sub.name
$currentCost = Get-AzConsumptionUsageDetail -StartDate $startDate -EndDate $endDate | Measure-Object -Property PretaxCost -Sum

 $x.Subscription = $sub.name
 $x.'cost in Euro' = [math]::round($currentCost.Sum,2)
 $x.'Period' = $currentBillingPeriod.name
 $report += $x 


Write-Host "Current Cost of Subscription :" $sub.name $currentCost.Sum
}

$report
$mailreport = $report

$sum = ($mailreport |  Measure-Object 'cost in Euro' -Sum).sum
$mailreport += '-'
$mailreport += '-'
$mailreport += 'Summe in Euro'
$mailreport += $sum
$mailreport
```

Comment: What's wrong with the existing code? Why is it not the best way?

Comment: You create objects with a property `cost in Euro`, but later you calculate the sum using an undefined property `cost in €`. That and adding to an array using `+=` is extremely time and memory consuming because the **entire** array needs to be rebuilt on each addition. Just do `$report = foreach ($sub in $subs){` and inside the loop simply output the object `$x`

Comment: y theo is right but do  $report = @(foreach ($sub in $subs){}) to get an array back in any case, even if only one element gets processed.  alterantively you could use another type of array - ArrayList and use the add method .

Comment: one question ist, how can I add the Value $sum into the secound column 'cost in Euro'

Comment: cost in Euro was copy paste error, I fixed it in the code...sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make a custom ps object, where you pour in the contents from the array, as well as the extra property you need

```
# Create new array
$Array = @()

# Add a custom object for the array for each subscription
$Array += New-Object psobject -Property @{Subscription = 'SubName'  ;Cost= $value; Sum = $value}

# Output array
$Array | Out-Default
```

Comment: The OP uses `$x = "" | Select 'Subscription','cost in Euro','Period'`, which is already creating a custom object...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution
any improvements?

```
$sum = ($report |  Measure-Object 'cost in Euro' -Sum).sum

$report 
$total = New-Object PSObject
$total | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "cost in Euro" -Value $sum
$report += ''
$report += $total
```